# How to get a clean Windows 7 install

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, installation

So I got a new Asus laptop from BestBuy and you know how they customize it and put extra stuff on it and they don't give you the original OS disks anymore?  Well...

There's gotta be a way to get a clean Windows 7 install (I've got the key on the bottom of my laptop).  I'm thinking I can maybe download a trial or something from Microsoft and put in my key to make it valid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

1. Find out what type of OS you need x64 or x86
2. Get your hands on any version of Windows 7 (x64 or x86) other than Enterprise you can re-install if you get a copy that is not the one you own e.g. you own Premium and you have an Ultimate DVD then you need to recreate the DVD or edit the ISO and remove the sources/ei.cfg file... this allows you to select any OS type. If you get your hands on the type you own you don't need to worry about editing it.
3. Burn the ISO using the built-in image burning software and verify integrity and then re-install using the CD-Key that is on your label
4. If you don't have a DVD Burner/Drive you will need to create a bootable USB Flash Drive follow this guide using the ISO you acquired if you have the DVD and no DVD drive you will need to create an ISO on another computer with it. http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2009/12/-the-usb-flash-drive.ars

Make sure you BIOS is set to boot from Removable Devices before Hard Drives so you can start the installer.

Use this webpage to help find ISO's online if you are desperate https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/securedownloads/default.aspx it lists the ISO names that you can search for and possibly find the ISO on a site like rapidshare then use the hash listed to verify that the ISO is safe using something like http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html

Comment: If you get ISO of different version, it may be easier to simply use Microsoft's USB creator tool as linked above, then delete the sources/ei.cfg after the process is finished.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can download from here. I have no idea if it's considered illegal or not. More legal than a torrent I think, if that makes any sense. It's MS's "secret" download distribution official link.

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/10/23/windows-7-32-bit-x86-direct-download-links/